# Is there a way to import aggregated sales into quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

Is there a way to import aggregated sales into quickbooks using the webconnector.

For example. I have 500 dollars in sales, 300 dollars in liquer sales, and 200 dollars in discounts.

How do I import this data. Do i need to import all the line items and have quickbooks sum it up (which is terrible i feel).

Or can i just import the rolled up data?

If i can do the rolled up data, how would i do that? If not how do i have quickbooks magically sum up the line items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an invoice with a bunch of line items, it's always going to automatically sum up all of the line items to show the total invoice amount/balance.

With that said, if you simply don't want the actual line item detail to go into QuickBooks, there's a number of ways you can do that, *but you should probably talk to your accountant first or actually find out how the accountant wants the data entered into QuickBooks first.*

e.g. your question doesn't really sound programming related, it's more of a "how do I use QuickBooks question".

The most common ways of not sending line item detail are to either:

- Just send an invoice with a single line item, for the sum of all of the stuff

OR

- Send a Journal Entry, which is a base-level transaction that only allows a single amount

Comment: The journal Entry approach is what Accounting wanted. Thank you so much